# SVG line width issue

Tags: html, css, svg, line

I started my svg learning. And I want to do some skills bar with the svg line.

But there is something I didn't understand. I create 2 lines per skills (one empty, and one with the percentage of knowledge).

The problem is : The two first lines have half the height I give with stroke width. And the other lines have the good height...

here is a jsbin : http://jsbin.com/lewimonize/edit?html,css,output

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: the line is clipped in half by the view box.

When you draw a line on the `y="0"` axis, half of the line width is above the axis, and half is below it. Combined with the `viewBox` which starts at `y=0`, the half of the line that is above will be clipped.

You have three options:

- Move the lines lower, so that the first one starts at `y1="2.5"`, for example
- Move the viewbox up: `viewBox="0 -2.5 100 100"`
- Add `overflow="visible"` to the `svg` element

Comment: But another problem i've got : I want to center the div with the skills bar. I try a lot of things, but nothing works, or badly (eg. the svg lines react weirdly)